# HTML pre tag auto-select

Tags: html, pre

Is it possible to auto-select the text in a PRE tag without the use of Javascript?

Comment: What kind of auto-select do you mean? Do you mean that the whole content should be selected when the user just focuses that element?

Comment: Select on focus would work for me or have the content selected on page load.

Comment: All the options I see online seem to use Javascript, or worse Flash. Seems like a lot of hassle for something so simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to use scripting to achieve that. There might be some accessibility tools out there that does that for you on form elements (like autofocusing on the first input field in a form) but probably not for arbitrary elements and depending on your actual use-case this might not be an option for you (if it even exists).

And to my knowledge the whole range selection in JavaScript is still not standardized AND implemented by all relevant browser manufactures in that standardized way ;-) ( http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html )

Comment: Ah, maybe I should leave it then. I could simply write some better on-screen instructions for users on how to drag, select and copy. :)